# mysterious url rewrite apache/php

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have a plain vanilla Apache php-fpm setup on ubuntu Precise. I have the rewrite module enabled but no rewrite rules anywhere in Virtualhost or directory level nor is there any .htaccess file. However, domain.com/abc launches domain.com/abc.php

Is there something in the default apache or php setup that enables this. Pls advise.

Comment: I would refer to this question - http://serverfault.com/questions/366638/how-to-prevent-apache2-from-accepting-urls-without-a-file-extension. Also note that this isn't related to programming entirely and you would have a better chance of posting on a more appropriate stack exchange such as serverfault.

Comment: Thanks Austin for the link which has useful info.. Will take care to post server related stuff on Serverfault next time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is called `MultiViews` and you have to disable it...

`Options -MulviViews`

Comment: Spot on! Removing this and restarting apache fixed it.. Thanks Darhazer.